# How to get API endpoints in Android

Tags: android

I want see API endpoints address in one APK. 
Such as network tab in websites. 
How can I see API endpoints from APK?

Comment: Have you tried the [Network Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler)?

Comment: @tomerpacific just show my app! I want check another app

Answer (score 0):

For You can explore tools like JADX or other similar tools to decompile the APK.
Search for classes that deal with network requests.

Comment: Thanks but this decompile apps can not show proguarded apps!